# I’m trying to write a function in javascript that Returns the number of times a number occurs as a digit in another number

Tags: javascript, filter

The second input number will always be between 0 and 9, and I must use the filter method. This is what I have so far:

```js
const countOccurrencesFilter = (number, target) => {
  let numStrArr = number.toString().split('');
  let targetStr = target.toString();
  let count = numStrArr.filter = (numStrArr => numStrArr[0] === targetStr).length;
  return count;
};
```

Comment: Could you put sample input and expected output ?

Comment: You have a typo: `numStrArr.filter(`

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there, you're assigning a key to `numStrArr` named `filter` whereas in actual you need to call the method. you need use

```
numStrArr.filter(numStrArr ...
```

not

```
numStrArr.filter = (numStrArr
```

```js
const countOccurrencesFilter = (number, target) => {
  let numStrArr = number.toString().split('');
  let targetStr = target.toString();
  let count = numStrArr.filter(numStrArr => numStrArr === targetStr).length;
  return count;
};

console.log(countOccurrencesFilter(121, 1))
console.log(countOccurrencesFilter(000, 1))
```

**P.S:-** Also no sense of using numStrArr[0] as you splited values will always be one character long only as you're spliting with `''`

Comment: Ahhh thank y’all so much

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
let count = numStrArr.filter = (numStrArr => numStrArr[0] === targetStr).length;
```

To

```
let count = numStrArr.filter(numStrArr => numStrArr === targetStr).length;
```

Comment: What the point of use numStrArr[0]?

Comment: you are correct i didn't notice that :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your purpose.

```js
const countOccurrencesFilter = (number, target) => {
  let numStrArr = number.toString().split('');
  let targetStr = target.toString();
  let count = numStrArr.filter(digit => digit === targetStr).length;
  return count;
};

console.log(countOccurrencesFilter(11211, 1));
```